# cant insert new data into database table but the other part of the code is working

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i am trying to insert these data into the table of my database, but it is not working. there is an error said that Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Set'. what is this error actually? cant get any idea what to do with this

```
            //insert clientID into traderecords.
            SqlCommand sqlinsertCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT TradeRecords Set ClientID = @clientID", hookUp7);
            sqlinsertCmd.Parameters.Add("@clientID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = clientID;
            sqlinsertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //insert stockname into traderecords.
            SqlCommand sqlinsertCmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT TradeRecords Set StockName = @stockname", hookUp8);
            sqlinsertCmd2.Parameters.Add("@stockname", SqlDbType.Int).Value = stockname;
            sqlinsertCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //insert amount of unit into traderecords.
            SqlCommand sqlinsertCmd3 = new SqlCommand("INSERT TradeRecords Set Amount = @amountofunit", hookUp9);
            sqlinsertCmd3.Parameters.Add("@amountofunit", SqlDbType.Int).Value = amountofunit;
            sqlinsertCmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //insert total price into traderecords.
            SqlCommand sqlinsertCmd4 = new SqlCommand("INSERT TradeRecords Set TotalPrice = @answer", hookUp10);
            sqlinsertCmd4.Parameters.Add("@answer", SqlDbType.Int).Value = answer;
            sqlinsertCmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //insert current date into traderecords.
            SqlCommand sqlinsertCmd5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT TradeRecords Set CurrentDate = @datetime", hookUp11);
            sqlinsertCmd5.Parameters.Add("@datetime", SqlDbType.Int).Value = datetime;
            sqlinsertCmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //insert price per unit into traderecords.
            SqlCommand sqlinsertCmd6 = new SqlCommand("INSERT TradeRecords Set PricePerUnit = @stockpriceperunit", hookUp12);
            sqlinsertCmd6.Parameters.Add("@stockpriceperunit", SqlDbType.Int).Value = stockpriceperunit;
            sqlinsertCmd6.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //insert payment type into traderecords.
            SqlCommand sqlinsertCmd7 = new SqlCommand("INSERT TradeRecords Set PaymentType = 'Buy'", hookUp13);
            sqlinsertCmd7.Parameters.Add("Buy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "Buy";
            sqlinsertCmd7.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //insert client nameinto traderecords.
            SqlCommand sqlinsertCmd8 = new SqlCommand("INSERT TradeRecords Set ClientName = @clientname", hookUp14);
            sqlinsertCmd8.Parameters.Add("@clientname", SqlDbType.Int).Value = clientname;
            sqlinsertCmd8.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The main issue is you are trying to use `UPDATE` syntax for `INSERT` commands.  `INSERT` commands consist of a list of columns to INSERT, followed by a `values(xxx, yyy)` list of values for those columns.

Comment: you need a [SQL tutorial](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/)

Comment: ah...how dumb am i...thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Insert Syntax is Wrong**

Apply this syntax to All Statements

```
 SqlCommand sqlinsertCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT TradeRecords(ClientID) 
 values(@clientID)";
sqlinsertCmd.Parameters.Add("@clientID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = clientID;
            sqlinsertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```